# What is the error in my SQL synatx?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Exported a MySQL database on one of my servers and am trying to import it on my new server. All done through phpMyAdmin.

MySQL says

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jobs` (    `id` mediumint(9) NOT
>   NULL,    `title` varc' at line 12

That area of code is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jobs` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descshort` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descr` varchar(7000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postdate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

One thing I might note is that I exported this from phpMyAdmin version 4.4.4 and MySQL 5.6, to my new server which is running phpMyAdmin 4.5.02 and MySQL 5.6

Any idea what might be causing this?

**EDIT:**

The table created before it successfully is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `horses` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `bgcolor` varchar(7) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `bgimgurl` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `htop` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `hbottom` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ptext` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `linktext` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `linktarget` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sord` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c365d2/1/0, but from your error message I think that your query is trimmed. `... title varc'`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong either.  Can you post lines 1-11 of your query as well?

Comment: @AndrewCoder I added some info to the OP

Comment: Thanks.  I still don't see anything wrong there.

Comment: @AndrewCoder I can possibly email you the file

Comment: Use http://pastebin.com/ ... I'll take a look but can't make any promises on a solution :)

Comment: @SpaghettiCoder if you paste just this CREATE TABLE statement in the SQL box of phpMyAdmin, does it work?

Comment: it looks awesome. it works. Now show your script

Comment: It's likely the problem is on the line before the statement you have posted.

Comment: @AndrewCoder Here's the bit of the query in which it can be found http://pastebin.com/ycLc0hDc

Comment: @Spaghetti Coder : Ran what you posted with the part that is throwing out error (table before, inserts and create jobs table) without any problems...How did you export the data and how are you importing it?  mysqldump?